# Buddypress bp_has_members function custom search with meta query

Tags: buddypress

In buddypress bp_has_members(), function how to include user meta key search . Now by default these values set as false

```
    'meta_key'            => false,   
    'meta_value'          => false,
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.